# parse json files directly and store them to hadoop and make a query to hadoop directly to get the data as required

Tags: php, json, hadoop

In my project a large set of data comes from server in json format. To get this data a cron task  is scheduled to run on every hour and it returns data of that one hour which we are saving into a file.
This set of data will be used for analytical purpose and will have a lot of measurement points based on which analytical report and graph will be presented. 
Now since data will be heavy ,it is decided to use HADOOP for data storage.
I have read a lot articles and found there is a mapper file for input processing and reducer file for output but not found good example for dynamic data.

But i want to know how we can parse my json files directly and store them to hadoop and make a query to hadoop directly to get the data as required and accessed from Php/Javascript .

Please suggest me the approach and/or examples to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation somewhat similar before, and used [json2csv](https://github.com/jehiah/json2csv) to convert the json files to csv, and then loaded the result into Hive for further analysis.

Of course, this approach would only work if your json schema is fixed (i.e, you know in advance the fields you want to map).

Check out the documentation, there's a very clear example on how to use the tool.

Comment: can u guide me on the approach how i should proceed